# How can I make this code tail recursive?

Tags: tail-recursion, oz

The following code is intended to append two lists.

```
fun {AppendLists L1 L2}
    if L1 == nil then L2
    else
        L1.1 | {AppendLists L1.2 L2}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is already tail-recursive. You have recursion as the last statement, so you are calculating the result first, and then call the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see why your code is already tail-recursive, here's the same code with a bit less syntactic sugar. Your function as been converted to a procedure with an extra argument to store the result (this is denoted by a facultative '?').

```
proc {AppendLists L1 L2 ?R} 
  if L1 == nil then L2
  else K in 
     R = L1.1 | K
     {AppendLists L1 L2 K}
  end
end
```